# Fade in/out elements

Tags: jquery

I have [this](http://codepen.io/Pezmo82/pen/KrAVbZ) working on a project, but I would like to do the same effect at the top and bottom of the page.

E.g.  At the bottom of the page, elements fade in when scrolling into view / fade out when scrolling out of view. The same goes for the top of the page, elements fade out going out of view and fade back in coming into view.

I have tried to create the opposite effect but they seem to cancel each other out and no elements show or they flicker when scrolling.

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".fade").each(function() { 
        var height = $(".header").outerHeight(true);

        if (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < height / 1.5) { 
            $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0);
        } else {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 1); 
        }       
    });
});
```

Is this possible to do or am I missing something?

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 0):

the main idea about showing/hiding elements on the page while scrolling is checking at every scroll event if these blocks are in the current view or not
the probleme with your code is that fadeOut/In hide the element at the end of the animation (display: none), so after that we cannot get the current offset().top correctly
what I suggest you to do is just changing the opacity of your blocks by using fadeTo();

I made this example for you
https://jsfiddle.net/9uqom17x/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var height = $(window).innerHeight();
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop()+height;

    $(".fade").each( function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            var _scrollTop = $this.offset().top;
            var _height = $this.innerHeight();

            if(_scrollTop+_height/2 < currentScroll ){
        if(! $this.hasClass("active")){
          $this.stop().addClass("active")
            .fadeTo(500, 1);        
        }
            } else {
                $this.stop().removeClass("active")
            .fadeTo(500, 0);
            }
    });
}).trigger("scroll");
```

Have fun with it.